# Convert Raw Velodyne VLP16 pcap to bagFile

Tags: ros, bagfile, vlp16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have some raw velodyne VLP16 data in a pcap file.  Is there a way to convert it to a ros bagFile?

Here is a link to the raw log file:  https://goo.gl/MJDfWA

Thanks,

Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213080/convert-raw-velodyne-vlp16-pcap-to-bagfile/) by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is preliminary VLP16 support in the ROS [velodyne driver](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne), but it is not yet released.

**Update:** VLP-16 support is now released as binary packages in both Indigo and Kinetic.

Since that version is not released, you would need to build it [from source](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne) in a catkin workspace. (Ask if you don't know how to do that.)

Once you have built that driver in your catkin workspace, run these commands in separate terminal windows:

```
roscore
```

...

```
rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=/your/pcap/path/data.pcap _read_once:=true
```

...

```
rosrun rosbag record -O your_vlp16_070815.bag /velodyne_packets
```

See the [rosbag record documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record) for other options and details.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/23272/dwolfe/) on 2015-07-20**:
I built my driver into my catkin workspace but after executing the first rosrun "rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=/your/pcap/path/data.pcap _read_once:=true" it gives me a fatal error (Error opening Velodyne socket dump file). Any suggestions as to why?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-21**:
Is the path to your PCAP file correct?

**Comment by [dwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/23272/dwolfe/) on 2015-07-23**:
yes that was the problem. Thanks. It seems like the last two commands should be run simultaneously. Is that True? In order to capture the whole pcap file? or does it not matter?
Is this only recording the velodyne packets? no points show up when i rosbag play the file in rviz

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-23**:
All three commands should be run in separate terminal windows. To get all the packets, you should probably start the velodyne_driver several seconds after starting rosbag.

**Comment by [dwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/23272/dwolfe/) on 2015-07-30**:
Once I have the bag file how can I view it?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-31**:
Use `rosbag play` to publish /velodyne_packets, then use velodyne_pointcloud and rviz to view the results, as if using with the actual device.

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-01-30**:
After I run the second command, it says
"[ERROR] [1485795341.945746381]: unknown Velodyne LIDAR model: VLP16"
Do you have any idea?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-01-30**:
Please open a new page to ask a new question.

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-01-30**:
Hi, I have posted the new question here http://answers.ros.org/question/253321/meet-error-when-implementing-velodyne_driver-command-for-vlp-16/
Can you help me

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-07**:
@joq Should there be /velodyne_pakcets in rostopic list?? after I run:

```
rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=/your/pcap/path/data.pcap _read_once:=true
```

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-02-08**:
Yes, there should.

**Comment by [Pelacho](https://answers.ros.org/users/28393/pelacho/) on 2017-04-26**:
Hi there, I got this in one window: end of file reached -- done reading.

but the recording windows remains: Recording to grabacion.bag. and never finish

I finish it manually and nothing appear when I rosplay it

**Comment by [sohel](https://answers.ros.org/users/32541/sohel/) on 2017-11-13**:
I am getting .bag.active file in my home directory. where is my .bag file

**Comment by [mathbeaudry](https://answers.ros.org/users/32841/mathbeaudry/) on 2017-12-02**:
I got the same result as Pelacho, what could we do with this ?

**Comment by [GuimingChen](https://answers.ros.org/users/52726/guimingchen/) on 2020-03-20**:
Hi, I was trying to do the same thing. But I realized that the recorded rosbag file has some missing frames compared with the pcap file. (I did make sure that I ran the record before start playing the pcap file) Is this expected? Is there a way to capture all the frames in pcap file?